# How do I test a controller with rspec-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller

I want to test that my edit recipe page renders using rspec, though it doesn’t route to

```
    recipes/edit
```

it routes to recipes/id/edit (id being replaced with a number)

my current test looks like this

```
 describe "Show Edit Recipe Page" do

  it "should display edit recipe  page" do
    get :edit
    response.should be_success
    response.should render_template(:edit)
  end
end
```

how can i test this page correctly, at the moment my tests are failing

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

Your example doesn't include the code needed to actually test a controller object. RecipeController is not defined in your spec.

#### Solution

Make sure your controller specs live under spec/controllers or have an explicit `type: :controller` set. Then, actually describe a controller, either using the implicit subject or by setting up a controller instance in a before or test block. As the most basic example:

```
describe RecipeController do
  # test something using the implied RecipeController.new
end
```

#### More Reading

[RSpec Controller Specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11/docs/controller-specs)

Answer (score 1):

The `get` needs the id of the recipe passed in the params hash:

```
let(:recipe) { Factory.create(:recipe) }

it "should display edit recipe page" do
  get :edit, :id => recipe.id
  response.should be_success
  response.should render_template(:edit)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It throws an `ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)`