# Ruby on Rails: How can I test a route with rspec that has a unique ID in?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

I'm trying to do this:

- [How do I test a controller with rspec-rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185552/how-do-i-test-a-controller-with-rspec-rails)

My test is as follows:

```
describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "edit" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    log_in user 
    #visit edit_user_path(user) <-- did not work
  end

describe "page" do
  it "should render edit page" do
    get :edit, :id => user.id
    should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update")
    should have_selector('h2',    text: user.username)
    should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user")
  end
end

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Save changes" }
  it { should have_content('error') }
end
```

end

I tried adding `get :edit, :id => user.id` but it throws an exception:

```
Failure/Error: get :edit, :id => user.id
 ArgumentError:
   bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
```

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
visit edit_user_path(user.id)
```

I'm unsure from reading about things though which method (get vs visit) is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure that your test file has a block like:

```
 describe UsersController do
   # your tests here
 end
```

2) try to rewrite the get like this

```
 it "should render edit page" do
    get :edit, :id => user.to_param
    should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update")
    # ...
 end
```

Comment: @David Cowden - The key difference here is that `UsersController` is passed to the `describe` method, so that the example group is set up correctly to issue HTTP requests to your controller under test.

Comment: @Hugo thanks.  I think this works too.  Is there an advantage to specifying `UsersController` in your describe block?  Also, is `get` preferred to `visit`?  It seems everyone is suggesting `get` but I found `visit` works and is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
describe "page" do
  it "should render edit page" do
    p = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    get :edit, :id => p.id
    should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update")
    should have_selector('h2',    text: user.username)
    should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user")
  end
end
```